# node-mongodb-native, how do I create data validator before I do CRUD operations with express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

`Model` module:

```js
exports.create = function(id, cb) {...}
exports.update = function(id, cb) {...}
exports.deleteOne = function(id, cb) {...}
...
```

Where should I put the `mongodb` data validator before I do the `CRUD` operation with `node-mongodb-native` driver?

I want to check the `data` passed from the client.

I know `mongoose`, it has some `schema`, you can define the data validator like type `String`, `Number` or something.

Comment: Indeed, mongoose will fit your question. you can build a scheme, and then define validation inside the scheme, or outside the scheme. more information can be found here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: @bar.m Thanks for anwser! I search so many pages. But still can not find  any examples or blogs explain my question.